# c# disposing syntax

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I've had to implement Dispose() functionality recently, and have come across 1 line method, 2 line methods and more comprehensive methods.

A 1 line method/functionwould simply call something like "context.Dispose", but the method I picked up was this:

```
    bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed && disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Is this syntax merely to stop Dispose() being called more than once?

Comment: You forgot the finalizer. Also make Dispose(bool) virtual.

Comment: This can help: [Implementing IDisposable and the Dispose Pattern Properly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P)

Comment: That's the legacy dispose pattern. IMO there is little reason to use it anymore.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - If thats the case what should be used in its place?

Comment: Depends on the situation. A `SafeHandle` as the direct owner of the unmanaged resources, and a simple `Dispose` method without finalizer as indirect owner.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: *You* not having seen the need to use it lately doesn't mean it's not needed at all any more.

Comment: @Maarten Knee-jerk addition of a finalizer simply to call Dispose(false) is not usually a good thing.  See http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2011/11/12/ABriefNoteOnObjectMortality.aspx for details on the drawbacks of having a finalizer that doesn't result in freeing unmanaged resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've posted is partially the [Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). As someone pointed out there should be a corresponding `Dispose(false)` in a finalizer ("destructor").  The finalizer should be used to dispose of unmanaged resources.  If you don't have unmanaged resources to deal with (i.e. you don't have anything to do when `disposing` is `false`), you don't need a `Dispose(false)` and thus don't need a finalizer.  This means that`Dispose(true)` is the only path, so you don't need `Dispose (bool)` (and thus don't need to implement the Dispose Pattern) and can move it's body into `Dispose` (and remove the check for `disposing`) and just implement `Dispose`.  For example:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _context.Dispose();
}
```

Classes that don't implement their own finalizer (destructor) are not put on the finalizer list so there's no need to call `GC.SuppressFinalize`.

In general, this is enough if you're creating a class.  But, sometimes you can derive from classes that implement this pattern.  In which case you should implement support for it in your class (override `Dispose(bool)` and do the `disposing` check and `Dispose` of any managed resources).  Since the base class implements `IDisposable` and calls a `virtual Dispose(bool)` in its `Dispose()`, you don't need to implement `Dispose()` yourself, but you have to call the base's `Dispose(bool)` in your `Dispose(bool)`.  For example:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if(disposing) _context.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

If you're calling into the base and it's implemented the Dispose Pattern, then you also don't need to call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` because it's already doing it.

You can do the whole `disposed` thing if you want; I find that it hides multi-dispose bugs though.

Comment: Peter are you also saying I should ignore GC.SupressFinalize() too?

Comment: If you don't have a finalizer, there's nothing to suppress.  I.e. C# classes without a finalizer (destructor) are not put in the finalization list, and don't need to be suppressed.

Comment: Peter, thanks for your help - this is all very new, so clear explanations are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

That is only part of the pattern. The other part missing here is that `Dispose(false)` would be called by a Finalizer.

The `_disposed` state flag can also be used to check and throw `ObjectDisposedExceptions` in your methods.

The full pattern is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Jon Skeet provides good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579199/purpose-of-dispose-calling-disposeisdisposing-pattern-in-c), and IMO this pattern is overkill for most situations unless you also have unmanaged resources. If not, just dispose of your managed resources and `GC.SuppressFinalize` in the `Dispose()` interface implementation. Use the `_disposed` flag only if you intend throwing `ObjectDisposedExceptions`.

Comment: Jon doesn't really go into a lot of detail there other than "I don't follow this pattern often".  Joe Duffy goes into some detail on finalization and the consequences of having a finalizer that doesn't free unmanaged resources here: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2011/11/12/ABriefNoteOnObjectMortality.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I use the following two forms of dispose based on the class need:

**Method 1 (For a class with managed and un-managed resources or with derived classes):**

```
class ClassHavingManagedAndUnManagedCode : IDiposable
    {
        private volatile bool _disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    //Do managed disposing here.
                }

                //Do unmanaged disposing here.
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

            _disposed = true;
        }

        ~ClassHavingManagedAndUnManagedCode()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
```

**Method 2 (For a class with only managed resource / sealed class / class that has not child classes):**

```
    class ClassHavingOnlyManagedCode  : IDiposable
    {
        private volatile bool _disposed = false;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                //Dispose managed objects.
                _disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any child classes of ClassHavingManagedAndUnManagedCode should just follow the protected dispose method pattern and call the base.Dispose at the end of the Dispose method.

Also guard all public methods (atleast ones that are using the members that are disposed) using a method /check that throws ObjectDisposedException if the class instance is already disposed.

FxCop will always ask you to implement the ClassHavingManagedAndUnManagedCode form of Dispose even if you do not have any unmanaged resources.

Comment: If you don't have an unmanaged resources you don't need the finalizer.  In fact, by having it you've increased the stress on the GC.  An object cannot be collected until the finalizer has run so the object is "kept alive" until the system has time to call the finalizer.  See my answer for detail on not needing the finalizer and it's consequence on `Dispose(bool)`  See also http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2011/11/12/ABriefNoteOnObjectMortality.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie I agree with you that we do not need the finalizer if we do not have unmanaged code. Hence I have given two different variants of dispose pattern, one for class with managed code and one without. Also if we do a GC.SupressFinalize, I am not sure if we are adding any stress in GC.

Comment: You have a bug in your method 2 code, you don't dispose of anything unless Dispose is called twice `if(_disposed) {/* dispose managed objects */} _disposed = true;`

Comment: If you do *all* the cleanup in Dispose(bool) when `disposing` is true **and** you have a finalizer (destructor) then you should have a call to GC.SuppressFinalize (either in Dispose() or Dispose(bool) when `disposing` is `true`) to reduce the stress on the GC (well, the finalizer--but, without SuppressFinalize you increase the risk of objects staying alive to gen2 which stresses the GC)

Comment: @Ganesh - thanks for th input it was very much appreciated. I've accepted Peter's answer as it helped me understand a little more about Dispose() but I've voted your answer up as it was particularly useful and will be used again in the future.

Comment: Is there any scenario in which a class with unmanaged resources requiring `Finalize`-based cleanup should inherit from a class whose purpose does not center around such cleanup?  In every case I can think of, it would be better to wrap the unmanaged resource in its own finalizable object (which could be a private class nested within the type that uses it), so the containing class would not need to worry about cleanup finalization.